# Node.js fs.writeFile asynchronous before process.exit(0) executes

Tags: node.js, fs

I have found this question on SO but have not found any good answers.

I am using node 0.10.40.

I am spawning a child process with `child_process.execFile` and in that process I am doing some file I/O with `fs.writeFile`. However, the process is exiting with `process.exit(0)` before the callback for `fs.writeFile` executes or the filo I/O even finishing.

Any idea on how I can delay the process exiting **without** `setTimeout`. I **don't** want to use a timeout because if I do that I might as well use `fs.writeFileSync`. Has anybody found a solution to this issue?

**[EDIT]**

Simply putting the `process.exit(0)` in the callback of the fs.writeFile is not what I am looking for here because consider this scenario:

> You have a program that spawns child processes. In these child processes, you perform HTTP requests, dump the packet data, perform logic on packet data, then kill process

So basically putting the `process.exit(0)` inside the `writeFile`'s callback works when the **only** thing that you child process does is this one file I/O. But on a larger scale, this won't work if you actually want to do a decent amount of logic in this process, and "dump" information from time to time. **This process's "life span" is not dependent on the file I/O**. It is dependent on the logic you perform on the packet data. The dump is more for looking back and debugging in this scenario.

Comment: So basically, what you really need is something that will help you manage asynchronous operations. That can be done with a module like [`async`](https://github.com/caolan/async), or promises, or various other solutions.

Answer (score 5):

You only need to make sure that you are calling the `process.exit();` on the callback of `fs.writeFile`, e.g.:

file index.js:

```
var child_process = require('child_process');

child_process.exec('node b.js', function(error, stdout, stderr){
    console.log(stdout);
});
```

file b.js:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var count = 0;

function ret(aux){
  count++;
  if(count==4){
    console.log("done i/o operation");
    count = 0;
    process.exit();
  }
}
fs.writeFile('message.txt', 'writing something...', 'utf8', ret); 
fs.writeFile('message.txt', 'writing something...', 'utf8', ret);
fs.writeFile('message.txt', 'writing something...', 'utf8', ret);
fs.writeFile('message.txt', 'writing something...', 'utf8', ret);
```

EDIT: 
I added multiple I/O calls as you asked on the comments, basically, you can count how many times your callback was called, and when it reaches a predefined value, you call `process.exit();`

Comment: thank you for your answer, but this will not help me if I need to do multiple filo I/O in the child process with multiple callbacks

Comment: Check my edit @Jeremy , you can count how many times the callback was called.

Comment: this answer is not wrong, so I gave it an upvote. But it is not solving the problem in the bigger picture. Please see my recent edits